# Template function default parameter

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, default

```
//template.h using MSVC++ 2010
#pragma  once
#include <iostream>
using std::ostream;
template <typename T, typename U> class Pair {
  private:
    T first;
    U second;

  public:

    // Pair() ;
    Pair ( T x = T() , U y = U() ) ;
    template<typename T, typename U> 
    friend ostream& operator<< ( ostream& thisPair, Pair<T, U>& otherPair );

};
template <typename T, typename U> 
Pair<T, U>::Pair ( T x , U y ) : first ( T ( x ) ), second ( U ( y ) ) 
{cout << x << y;}

template <typename T, typename U> 
ostream& operator<< ( ostream& os, Pair<T, U>& otherPair )
{
    os << "First: " << otherPair.first 
<< " "<< "Second: " << otherPair.second << endl;
    return os;
}

//template.cpp
int main()
{
    int a = 5, b = 6;
    Pair<int,int> pair4();
    Pair<int, int> pair1 ( a, b );
    cout<<pair4;
    cout<<pair1;
    return 0;
}
```

How to make a constructor or a member function to take default value?
The code above is giving linker error for pair4 when using cout statement.
The code works perfectly when cout<<pair4(); is commented.
I am trying to mimic a constructor taking 0,1 or 2 argument using a single default constructor in a template class.

Comment: Commenting out `cout<<pair4();` still causes compilation errors on g++: http://ideone.com/9usX9L.  Also it's really unclear why you're adding parentheses to either line beginning `cout<<` -- you could only do this if `pair4` or `pair1` is a function, function pointer, or object of a type that has an `operator()()`.  I'm surprised that `cout<<pair1();`, with the parentheses, compiles at all on MSVC++.

Comment: What did you expect `pair4()` to do? The class has no `operator()()` member.  Did you mean to write `cout<<pair4;`?

Comment: @j_random_hacker: Yes the code won't work on GCC. This is how it works on VS.
Mooing Duck: If I implement Pair() then the code will run fine. I want to make Pair(x=0,y=0).

Comment: @Freiza Yes the code won't work on GCC. [I doubt that](http://ideone.com/ZxkdoJ), GCC supports `#pragma once`. These aren't VS specific errors.

Comment: Funny, when I put this in Visual Studio, I get [error C2065: 'cout' : undeclared identifier](http://rextester.com/WBDYLV27347).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from other errors like shadowing template parameters (which MSVC++ wrongly ignores), the problem is here:

```
Pair<int,int> pair4();
```

This declares a function instead of a variable. This is because it can be syntactically both and C++ standard selects the most vexing parse: anything that can be interpreted by compiler as a declaration, will be interpreted as a declaration. The linker error then is that you try to print to `cout` address of a function that is never defined (has no address).

Side note: in GCC and Clang, you can actually link this because the address is immediatelly converted to `bool` for `operator <<` (there is no operator for printing function pointers to `ostream` and `bool` is the only available implicit conversion) which will always result in `true` (address of a declared function can never be `nullptr`) so the address itself is optimized away.

The fix is very simple:

```
Pair<int,int> pair4;
```

Comment: I couldn't upvote you since someone downvoted me in this question. And now I am again below 15. Btw, to everyone this answer worked. Thank You very much.